# HTML <Canvas> element support

Tags: android, html, webview, html5-canvas

https://caniuse.com/#feat=canvas  following this link i cant understand on which android OS version does WebView in android support the Canvas element in HTML5

Can anybody help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "Since Android 4.4 (KitKat), the WebView component is based on the Chromium open source project. WebViews now include an updated version of the V8 JavaScript engine and support for modern web standards previously missing in old WebViews. New Webviews also share the same rendering engine as Chrome for Android, so rendering should be much more consistent between the WebView and Chrome." - https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview

Comment: @Malcor i read this before, my question is clear